# Using vectors with GMP

Tags: c++, vector, gmp

I'm trying to use vectors with GMP.  But when I compile anything like this, I get "[...]\bits\vector.tcc    [Error] array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer".  Any data structure with dynamic size works - a deque would be best but I had even more errors popping up when I tried that.  How do I make this stop failing?

```
#include <vector>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(){
mpz_t test;
mpz_init(test);
std::vector<mpz_t> a_vector;
a_vector.push_back(test);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GMP numbers are not directly assignable (in other words, you can't do `mpz_t test = 0;' or`mpz_t test1l; test1 = test;`, I don't believe they can be used in standard C++ container types.

If you want to do that, you may want to use the C++ interface for GMP instead:
https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html

Comment: Or, if the OP wants to stay away from the GMP C++ wrapper, then maybe [`boost::multiprecision`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) is a good and generic alternative.